# AngularJs - How to loop an audio in ionic (nativeAudio)

Tags: cordova, loops, audio, ionic-framework

Can you please help me to make the audio files looping in js codes bellow ?

```js
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic']);
 
app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});
 
app.controller('AudioController', function($scope, $ionicPlatform) {
 
  var audio = [{
    id: 1,
    key: 'master',
    title: "The Master",
    track: 'sound/audio.mp3',
    genre: "This will be card Description",
    art: 'img/ionic.png'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    key: 'give',
    title: "Give",
    track: 'sound/audio.mp3',
    genre: "Alternative & Punk | Bright",
    art: 'img/ionic.png'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    key: 'morning',
    title: "Morning Stroll",
    track: 'sound/audio.mp3',
    genre: "Classical | Happy",
    art: 'img/ionic.png'
  }, ];
 
  $scope.audioTracks = Array.prototype.slice.call(audio, 0);
 
  $scope.player = {
    key: '' // Holds a last active track
  }
 
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
 
    $scope.playTrack = function(track, key) {
      // Preload an audio track before we play it
      window.plugins.NativeAudio.preloadComplex(key, track, 1, 1, 0, function(msg) {
        // If this is not a first playback stop and unload previous audio track
        if ($scope.player.key.length > 0) {
          window.plugins.NativeAudio.stop($scope.player.key); // Stop audio track
          window.plugins.NativeAudio.unload($scope.player.key); // Unload audio track
        }
 
        window.plugins.NativeAudio.play(key); // Play audio track
        $scope.player.key = key; // Set a current audio track so we can close it if needed 
      }, function(msg) {
        console.log('error: ' + msg); // Loading error
      });
    };
 
    $scope.stopTrack = function() {
        // If this is not a first playback stop and unload previous audio track
        if ($scope.player.key.length > 0) {
          window.plugins.NativeAudio.stop($scope.player.key); // Stop audio track
          window.plugins.NativeAudio.unload($scope.player.key); // Unload audio track
          $scope.player.key = ''; // Remove a current track on unload, it will break an app if we try to unload it again in playTrack function
        }
    };
  });
});
```